# to change some css property once backing to an already-visited page

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 2 pages, a link from first page to second one.`www.example.com/second.html`.

then a link from second page to a specific section on first one `www.example.com/first.html#specificSection`.

is there a way to change some css property on first page once backing from second one by Java Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```js
let urlChunks = window.location.href.split('#'); 
if (urlChunks.length === 2 && urlChunks[1] === 'specificSection') {
    // add your class
}
```

If `length` is 2, it means a parameter was found after `#`, checking its value is safe in the condition that follows the and.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the url on first page load, and if it is `www.example.com/first.html#specificSection` assume that the user came from the second page and apply any styling to your elements.

So you would check

```js
(function () {
  if (window.location.href === 'www.example.com/first.html#specificSection') {
    // do anything here
  }
})();
```

**UPDATE** according to @Ravenous comment
You can also check `document.referrer` and compare it with the url of your second page. That would be more precise way to detect if the user came from the second page I think.

Comment: There's `document.referrer` in JavaScript, if there's no server-side logic, just a web server that serves static files.

Comment: @Ravenous Yep, thanks. Never used it, nor was aware about it. Updated the answer to reflect that option.

Comment: Ideally, one should never rely on referrer. It should be stateless, so, when you are sharing a link like that, with a jump to a particular section to a friend, you expect your friend to see the very same thing you see, exactly like StackOverflow comments or answers, for example.

Comment: @Ravenous Yep, ideally any url must be stateless, but OP needs to differentiate the visitors coming back from second page for some reason.